# Properly set encoding to UTF-8, even then email come up with ? and �

Tags: java, email, encoding, utf-8, jakarta-mail

I am using javax.mail API for sending email to my Outlook. There are chinese and french characters in my Body.
I am properly setting body as

MimeMessage.setText(body, "UTF-8");

Also in the email I am checking the Headers. They are properly coming as :
Content-type: text/plain;
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

The funny thing is that from the Other Machine, the email is coming up fine, but when I try it from my desktop, It doesn't encode properly.

I am also checking logs by printing the body. They are properly coming up in chinese and french.
Help needed ?
Does it is anything to do with Sendmail??

Comment: Is the problematic Outlook connecting to a Microsoft Exchange server by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Should have worked; you only forgot to do the subject too. Especially as you checked the header. Encoding calls:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
message.setText(body, "UTF-8");
//message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
```

I think, your email settings on the desktop force the wrong encoding.

---

Paranoia: Check the body string, via a hard-coded u-escaped string:

```
message.setText("\u00e9\u00f4\u5837" + body, "UTF-8"); // éô堷
```

Comment: My subject is Normal Ascii. More Over I think there is no need to do message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"); As Headers are coming properly fine... Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

Comment: Yes setHeader not needed; copied from my list of error sources. Though the subject you could try; maybe Outlook looks only at the subject encoding? (Improbable.) One may only set the encoding to UTF-8 for the _outgoing_ email in Outlook. Maybe your mail server?