# What is the proper non ascii (UTF-8) email message text encoding in a multipart message

Tags: email, encoding, utf-8, smtp

I would like to send an email message with attachments. So the message should be multipart.

The encoded message body looks like:

```
From: another@address
To: an@address
Subject: Unimportant message
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_0_1457006650.1670256299458"
 ...
------=_Part_0_1457006650.1670256299458
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

Hello,

=E2=80=9ESomething here=E2=80=9C

------=_Part_0_1457006650.1670256299458
Content-Type: image/png; name=sample.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.png
Content-Description: sample.png

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAIAAAACUFjqAAABhGlDQ1BJQ0MgcHJvZmlsZQAAKJF9
  ...
FElEQVQY02P8z8WABzAxMIxKYwIATTQBHSBDi6AAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
------=_Part_0_1457006650.1670256299458--
```

Web MS Outlook and Gmail do not display non ASCII characters correctly showing a placeholder for each UTF-8 byte in the message body. For example:

[image]

I tried different `Transfer-Message-Encoding` values and different multipart layouts (multiple top-level sections, and nested as parts inside the root-multipart) but the result seem the same - it seems that Web Outlook does take into account the transfer encoding, but does not recognize the message text encoding as UTF-8.

Is this a problem with Outlook Web? Or the message should have some additional meta information or different multipart layout?

I probably could use an HTML encoding, but the message is generated from a template, so all non-ASCII symbols will have to be converted to entities automatically, if I understand correctly. We do not need any fancy formatting besides plain text message, so that option seems over-complicated.

Comment: It would have been better to post a *complete* example

Comment: What exactly would you want to see?

Comment: Something that could be tested?

Comment: If you say it is utf-8, use utf-8. Now you are using a escaped utf-8

Comment: @g00se OK, removed references to Java as it is not essential. The question is about email encoding.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The Content-Transfer-Encoding defines how the text in the message encoded to byte sequence. In my experiments it is not relevant. Direct encoding as UTF-8 is displayed exactly the same.

Comment: The question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561528/properly-set-encoding-to-utf-8-even-then-email-come-up-with-and

Comment: The email data shown is perfectly fine and formatted correctly. So, it has to be a parsing/display error on Outlook/Gmail's end.